# insert several items into a query

Tags: php, laravel

I get the following error when I make a query where I insert somes elements.

```
public function createScheduleTraining(Request $request)
{
    for ($i=0;$i<count($request->training_id);$i++){
             //create raw..
        $query=\DB::select('CALL procceding(3,1)');
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($query); $x++) {
            //create raw..
        }
        DB::disconnect('foo');
    };
}
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'held'
>   already exists (SQL: CALL procceding(3,1))

Comment: your procedure `procceding` throw that error. Check if not trying create new table.

Comment: And/or add the code to that procceding function in your question